# How long will it take for yeast culture to adapt to new flour

Tags: sourdough, starter

My starter is made from organic whole wheat. I feed it twice a day every 12 hours with 1:1 ratio of flour to water.

It almost triples in volume each feed.

I started it on April 12/2020

I decided to change my feeding to 50% white all purpose and 50% whole wheat. (Both organic/unbleached). That was 2 days ago. Now my starter is barely doubling but i see plenty of bubbles.

Is my starter slowly dying? Or just getting used to the new flour? If so how long will this take?

Here is an image of "Meredith"[image]

Thanks

Comment: Doubling volume on feeding is still fairly active so I would not at all call it dying.  Sourdough require patience even when well established.  Yours is still young and will go through a lot of growing cycles.

Comment: I also think your starter is fine. Wholemeal flour is more nutritious for yeast than white flour, so a smaller (but still substantial) increase is expected.

Answer (score 1):

1:

> How long will it take for yeast culture to adapt to new flour

Starter will adapt to the new flour ratio with 3-5 feeds (if you feed it daily, it should change to the new flour within 7 days).

---

2:

> Is my starter slowly dying? Or just getting used to the new flour? If so how long will this take?

Add some rye or wholewheat flour for a couple of feeds.
If you wish to add white flour - that should increase the gas pockets in your starter.

I'd give it three to four feeds before you see some hyper activity.

The thing is - depending on your temperature - the starter should be active the closer its is to ~30C.

I'd say, unless there's pink spots or or mould, then you should give up.

Re: Giving up: can be checked in this other starter question.
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/107641/83535